# Large-scale ODEs about boundary value problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'm doing FEM and have a problem about getting numerically stable solution for ODEs problems like:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{AY}, x\in[x_1,x_2]$$
in which $\mathbf{Y}$ stands for a large-scale vector (greater than $1000000\times1$), and $\mathbf{A}$ is its corresponding coefficient matrix. The elements in matrix $\mathbf{A}$ vary greatly, from $10^{-50}$ to $10^{50}$.

For small matrix, analytical solutions for such ODEs are simple. However, those does not work for large scale matrix, especially when the transfer distance $(x_2-x_1)$ is large. I used DQM to get a relatively stable solution, but still is not stable enough when the dimension of $\mathbf{A}$ gets bigger.

Thanks!

Comment: As the elements of $A$ vary so greatly, I would expect the eigenvalues do too and so the matrix ODE problem would be expected to be extremely [stiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation). Implicit solvers would be the way to go, though I doubt even these could account for 100 orders of magnitude difference in the coefficient values.

Comment: Yes, I tried several methods but all failed. As this is a boundary value problem, I also noticed that numerical solutions would be heavily influenced by very small initial disturbances. Is this because **A** is too stiff?

Comment: No, that would be because the matrix is [ill conditioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number). Just so you know, you are probably better off asking this on the [scientific computing stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) website. The people there know a lot more about these things than I do.

Comment: Great! your advice helps a lot